# Bump Cordova adal to a more recent version of the native library

Tags: ios, cordova, adal

I am using the [cordova adal library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova), which uses version 2.3.1 of the native [ios library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc). It looks like there has been over a year of updates since version 2.3.1 of the native library.

I am interested in forking the cordova adal repo and bumping from 2.3.1 to a more recent version. I've never had to update a cordova library, so I was hoping someone here may be able to help answer a couple questions:

- Would I face any breaking changes if I tried to fork and upgrade
  cordova adal to use a more recent version of this library?
- Does anyone know if there is a reason why the cordova adal library
  has not    been upgraded from 2.3.1?

This will be a first for me, so my plan was to use [this commit](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/pull/141/files) as a guide. This was how the cordova adal team upgraded to 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to some of the native developers and confirmed there would be some potential breaking changes. I do not know why an upgrade was not made though.